# Declaring class members

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a signal/slot connection in Qt (old syntax). In order to do that, I need to create a class. In that class, some members must be declared. Those members are: a variable `doverka` which is a **QString** and `text` which is a **QTextEdit widget**. The question is: how on earth do I declare them? Pardon me for the stupid question but I am new to classes. For me, declaring those is not that simple. I have already declared a member function and created a connection, but as the `doverka` and the `text` have not yet been declared, nothing works, naturally.

```
class MyObject : public QObject
   {
      Q_OBJECT
      public: /*how should I declare 'text' and 'doverka' here??? */

      public slots:
      void onClicked() {
         text.setText(doverka);
     }
   };

   QObject::connect(
   &btn_t,
   SIGNAL(clicked()),
   this,
   SLOT(onClicked()));
```

Comment: `QString doverka;` then `QTextEdit  text;`

Comment: that works as a declaration, very many thanks :) I still get some errors like "invalid declaration of member template in local class", "local class shell not have static data member", and "invalid use of 'this' in non-member function"... know how to solve this? I don't need any templates or stuff, I just need to get the thing work in signal/slot relation...thank you!

Comment: No idea because there are no templates in this code.

Comment: BTW, `QObject::connect(  ...` should be inside some function. You can't just put code anywhere. You may want to add a constructor for your `MyObject` class.

Comment: it is, in the `main` function... did you mean that?

Comment: In the main function, you cannot use `this` because it's a "pointer" on the current object. So, it's available in a method, only. Replace `this` by your `MyObject` instance.